# Flutter Barcode Scanning issue when 2 codes side-by-each

Tags: flutter, barcode-scanner

I have an issue where I am trying to scan a barcode which is directly underneath another barcode. One is a simple 1-D barcode (not the one I want) and the other is a 2-D PDF417 barcode.

Is there a plug-in or way of altering one of the existing barcode scanning apps to ONLY see the PDF417 code?

Comment: This is a little bit unclear as to whether you are trying to write an app to scan barcodes or whether you simply need to scan a barcode once...

Comment: I hope that's a sample driver's license you got from the Ontario DMV and not a real license

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't already a Flutter library, you will have to create your own bridge/bindings to a native library.

The actual implementation will depend on which library you choose to use, but most barcode scanning libraries have a way to enable/disable symbologies.

Using ZXing it looks something like

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(Collections.singletonList("PDF_417"))
```

Using the Google Vision barcode api it's

```
BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.PDF417)
        .build();
```